# What's the difference between exogenous and endogenous identifiers?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, econometrics, instrumental-variables, 2sls

What's the difference? Exogenous vs. Endogenous identifiers.

Answer (score 1):

In the first step, you project all the predictors (endogenous and exogenous) onto the space of exogenous predictors only. By a property of projection operator, the projection of exogenous $X_j$ is $X_j$ again. So formally speaking, you do "replace" but in reality, nothing happens.